# How to execute "del data.txt" using Process?

Tags: c#

The following trivial code is just an example that does not reflect my real scenario. 
I have tried it and it did not work.

I want to delete `data.txt` using `Process` rather than using `File` class.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "del data.txt";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine("Finished"); };

            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

How to execute `del data.txt` using `Process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "/C" argument to the process.

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C del data.txt";
```

Comment: @oded what do you mean by calling `del` directly?

Comment: @Oded `del` is a builtin command in `cmd`, not a real binary.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently because cmd doesn't handle arguments like that. You have to add /C (and maybe quotes) to the argument:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C \"del data.txt\"";
```